# Java Spring MVC redis issue in Redis Cache manager

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redis, pom.xml

I m trying to use Redis in Spring MVC. I have added Redis cache dependencies in `pom.xml` created configuration file for Redis but it keeps throwing error. Please see the error below.

```
`The type org.springframework.cache.transaction.AbstractTransactionSupportingCacheManager cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager`
```

This error is generated from the configuration file below:

```
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager;
    import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
    import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
    import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer;
    import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer;

    @Configuration
    public class RedisConfig {
        @Bean
        public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
            JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
            factory.setHostName("");
            factory.setPort(");
            factory.setPassword("");
            return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
            RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
            template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
            template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
            template.setValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class));
            return template;
        }
        
        @Bean
        public RedisCacheManager cacheManager() {
            RedisCacheManager cacheManager = RedisCacheManager.builder(jedisConnectionFactory()).build(); // The erorr is generated on this line
            return cacheManager;
        }

    }`
```

The error is generated on this code below:

```
        @Bean
        public RedisCacheManager cacheManager() {
            RedisCacheManager cacheManager = RedisCacheManager.builder(jedisConnectionFactory()).build(); // The erorr is generated on this line
            return cacheManager;
        }
```

**My pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project >
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>xxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>xxxx Maven Webapp</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <hsqldb.version>1.8.0.10</hsqldb.version>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- spring dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jstl dependency -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha01</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security Artifacts - START -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Data Redis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Please help me out. I m just a beginner and i cant understand how to resolve this issue and use redis. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Your project may import multiple spring-context-support.jar.

Comment: Dont understand what you mean. Can you please elaborate a bit more instead of just one line text. I m a beginner.

Comment: what you said has no link with the redis issue I m facing. If so then explain in detail how to fix it.

Comment: When multiple versions conflict, you can find unwanted versions and break dependencies

Comment: Thats not an answer. You need to provide solution as well rather than just one line,